# Scripting question

Tags: scripts

How do I create a script that asks a user for a file name then creates that file?

I have already tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get Script name of this file and create it
#Get Author's name of this file
#Add the date this file is ran
#Add a "Hello"

echo -n "Please type Script destination file name: "
read 0

echo -n "Please type your name: "
read name

if [ -z "$0" ]
then
    echo "No Script name given."
else
    echo "#Script: $0" > $0
fi

if [ -z "$name" ]
then
    echo "No name given."
else
    echo "#Author: $name" >> $0
    echo "#Date: `date`"  >> $0
fi
```

Comment: Do you want authors name, date and hello on file name or as contents inside the file?

Comment: I don't think `0` is a legal name for a user-created variable; although $0 will usually expand to the name by which the *current* script was invoked. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Thank you for responding heemay! and steeldriver, and for a perfect resolution heemay! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the use of $0 as a variable name. This is reserved for the name of the script being called; try creating a script with only `echo $0;`. Furthermore each integer variable beyond this is reserved for the arguments passed to the script.

Below is an updated version of your script that works as expected. I have changed $0 to $filename and $name to $username.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get Script name of this file and create it
#Get Author's name of this file
#Add the date this file is ran
#Add a "Hello"

echo -n "Please type Script destination file name: "
read filename

echo -n "Please type your name: "
read username

if [ -z "$filename" ]
then
    echo "No Script name given."
else
    echo "#Script: $filename" > $filename
fi

if [ -z "$username" ]
then
    echo "No name given."
else
    echo "#Author: $username" >> $filename
    echo "#Date: `date`"  >> $filename
fi
```

Comment: You should quote all the variables..

Comment: Good point @heemayl. I had simply converted the original script.